# Kicker vibrations

Tags: turbo-trainer, vibration

I have some kind of vibration while using my kickr, I have a feeling something is not aligned correctly, at a certain point in the rotation I feel a vibration.

Have changed

Cassette
bottom bracket
Jockey Wheels

Swapped large chainring for another old one.

I’m now wondering if I should buy whole new cranks with chainring included or start with a new chaining.

I guess I asking for opinions because its getting expensive replacing parts.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume the vibration does not occur when you ride the bike with a normal wheel on the road? Does it occur when you put the bike upside-down (or hang it from e.g. a string) and pedal with your hands? I think some vibration is normal, which is why indoor bikes can lead to complaints from neighbors living in the flat below you.

Comment: If my Kickr was to make noise, the first thing I'd do was to contact Wahoo. They replace defective units quite willingly.

Comment: I can feel the vibration in the cranks - its defo not right, just put the wheel back on went round the block, seemed ok to me - yeah I have emailed wahoo

Answer (score 1):

Wahoo have had a number of problems surrounding belt tension and bearings which lead to vibration and rumbling on both the Kickr and Kickr Core.  Some detective work with google will dig up many people with vibration issues.  There is a good article about some of the issues here: https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2019/01/wahoo-ceo-details-fixes-for-issues-surrounding-kickr-2018-kickr-core.html

My experience with Wahoo support was excellent - I sent them a short video clip of my 2yr old Kickr Core making a rumbling noise and they replaced with a refurbished unit which has been trouble free so far.

EDIT: I should note that at some combinations of cadence/power there can be some expected modest vibration - picking a different gear usually resolves it.

Comment: Tbh I don't think it's the kickr its the bike, I just changed the cassette and chain again, this time for a Shimano hg-ev chain it says it  supper narrow or something. It is better but still rough possibly the vibrations are gone still a bit loud and grindy - does a new chain and cassette need to bed in ?